# Local admin pass not documented correctly, I need to get in to fix domain issue!? (win 7)

Tags: windows-7, passwords

One of my users has managed to leave the domain. I can no longer manage his machine with my domain admin account.

Also for some reason his account name does not show up on the login screen - It just shows the local admin user name - no option to switch users.

He sent me his laptop - so I was planning on logging in with the documented local admin password - but whoever set it up (before I was in my current position) has not documented it correctly.

Any tips on how to get into the machine now?

Whats the best way to get into the machine without the password?

I would re-image it, but he is a remote user in charge of his own backups onto an external hard drive, and he hasn't done it in a month.

I need to get the data on this C: drive by monday.

Comment: ask him for his credentials? Get in the front door rather than the back?

Comment: Oh - right - ALSO... for some reason I cant switch users...the only option is "Backup" which is the name of the local admin account on the machine

Comment: Use Ophcrack, available [here](http://ophcrack.sourceforge.net/).